# Why my yubikey is not protected by a PIN to log into Google?

Tags: authentication, yubikey, fido

I just setted my yubikey on Google so I can login into Google without any passwords. However, I don't even have to put a PIN on the yubikey, it simply works. I find this very very dangerous as anyone with my yubikey would be able to access my Google account.

I've used yubikey for SSH login and I have to put the PIN. Why for Google login it does not ask me? Is there a way?

Is there a way to also make its OTP generation depend on a PIN?

I tried putting a PIN on FIDO2, but I still can log into Google without any PIN, I don't know what's that for

Comment: The threat model for security keys generally assumes that unauthorized parties don't have access to it.  Generally people use a YubiKey with FIDO2 as a second factor so that theft is less of a problem.

Comment: Usually, Yubikey works as the second factor for authentication, how did you set it up? I want to follow your approach, I am tied to input username and password to log in to google every day.

Answer (score 1):

Websites have the ability to specify whether or not they prompt you for the PIN.

References:
https://www.reddit.com/r/yubikey/comments/116z9ng/fido2_pin/
https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402836718866-Understanding-YubiKey-PINs

You can try this out yourself by registering and authenticating an account at https://webauthn.io/ - click on advanced settings, switch the User Verification between Required (asks for PIN) and Discouraged.